# how to modify the $strapi.login({}) default route in nuxt(custom login)

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, nuxt-strapi

I am using `nuxt-strapi` and I am authentication user by otp and for that I want to use `$strapi.login()` but the issue is the default endpoint for strapi login is auth/local which requires email and password but I want to modify it and use mobile number. I dont know how to modify the route for that so is there any option like in $auth I can modify the the login route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `nuxt-strapi` module doesn't allow you to change the login URL. What I would do in your case is directly call the OTP API endpoint and set the token manually.

```js
const token = await this.$strapi.$http.$post('otp/endpoint', {tel}) 
await this.$strapi.setToken(token)
await this.$strapi.fetchUser() //to get the user information
//or get the user via $http and set it manually
this.$strapi.setUser(user)
```

see for more info https://strapi.nuxtjs.org/strapi